# Where is my glut?

Tags: gcc, c

I try to compile c program :

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<GL/glew.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
void main(int argc, char **argv) {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glewInit();
        if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_2_0"))
            printf("Ready for OpenGL 2.0\n");
        else {
            printf("OpenGL 2.0 not supported\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        setShaders();

        glutMainLoop();
    }
```

using:

```
gcc -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL - lglut c.c
```

I got an error :

```
 gcc: error: lglut: No such file or directory
```

So I check :

```
 locate glut.h
 /usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
 /usr/include/GL/glut.h
 /usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut.html
```

also :

```
locate glut.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3.9.0
```

What should I do to make it compile ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after your code you have this command, using:

```
gcc -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL - lglut c.c
```

perhaps it should be using:

```
gcc -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lglut c.c
```

there may be an unintended space between the - and lglut

Comment: #include <stdio.h>